# Adobe Analytics Product Views not Showing as Metric

Tags: google-analytics, adobe, analytics, adobe-analytics

For a vast majority of my reports in AA, the list of available metrics does not include product views. I would really like to be able to see product views aggregated to be shown broken down by things like marketing channel, etc., but right now I can only add it as a metric to the products report.

Is the only way to accomplish this to use a custom event that is basically a mirror of the prodView event and set it to increment on each product view? I would prefer to use the out of the box prodView event, obviously.

Any and all input would be helpful!

Comment: If I recall correctly you have to set the variables up as merchandising variables or use a separate event as you suggested

Comment: Setting a custom event along with the prodView will make the metric available in conversion reports along with calculated metrics and segments. The prodView metric was designed to be used in your typical conversion funnel scenarios